# Trace to Opera Dragonfly

Tags: debugging, opera, remote-debugging, opera-dragonfly

I am using Opera on a Windows PC and developing for a device. I can telnet into the device and manually run the browser which gives me the browser output.

Is it possible to trace messages into both Dragonfly and the Opera console? I can see a window.alert() message show up in the console, but I would also like to trace messages for simpler debugging and status tracking both within Dragonfly on PC and Opera on the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function debug(text) {
  ((window.console && console.log) ||
   (window.opera && opera.postError) ||
   window.alert).call(this, text);
}
```

I'm not positive this will solve your problems (I don't have much experience with Dragonfly) but it seems that **opera.postError** is the general API call for console logging on Opera.

Comment: postError() might throw a "WRONG_THIS_ERROR" with that code.. but that was considered a bug and I hope we never released any versions with this issue..

Answer (score 2):

console.log will work in Opera and Dragonfly from Opera 11. We added support for both the Console and the Command Line APIs from Firebug. See http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/getting-opera-dragonfly-ready-for-opera-11/ for more information.